# Hankel function expansion for large arguement

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, taylor-expansion, bessel-functions

The leading order behaviour of the Hankel function for large arguments is known to be
$$
H_{n}^{(1)}(z)\sim\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}e^{i\left(z-\frac{n\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}
$$
as $z\to\infty$. I would like to know what the analytical form of the full expansion is i.e. if we write
$$
H_{n}^{(1)}(z)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}e^{i\left(z-\frac{n\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}f_{n}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)
$$
then I would like to know the power series expansion for $f_{n}(z)$. I can get the first few terms in Mathematica but I don't see how to derive a general form for the coefficients. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [See Hankel in DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotic expansion for the Hankel function can be found in [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.E5):

\begin{align}
 &{H^{(1)}_{\nu}}\left(z\right)\sim\left(\frac{2}{\pi z}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\omega}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}i^{k}\frac{a_{k}(\nu)}{z^{k}}\\
&\omega=z-\tfrac{1}{2}\nu\pi-\tfrac{1}{4}\pi\\
&a_{k}(\nu)=\frac{(4\nu^{2}-1^{2})(4\nu^{2}-3^{2})\cdots(4\nu^{2}-(2k-1)^{2})}{
k!8^{k}}\text{ for }k\ge1\\
&a_0(\nu)=1
\end{align}
for $-\pi<\operatorname{arg}z<2\pi$. It is obtained using a contour integral representation for the function (see [here](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Eshipman/47/volume2a2010/Sekeljik.pdf) section 7, for example).